# BIngbot on my network IP

Tags: bingbot

I was looking my apache logs and I find out this.

Log Line: 192.168.1.2 - - [30/Nov/2016:15:46:52 +0100] "GET http://www.Mywebsite.... HTTP/1.1" 200 5539 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"

This happen a few times with that IP, but i cannot understand how is bingbot executing from that IP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think https://serverfault.com/ would be a more suitable place to ask this kind of question.